# boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is in my book

```
rlr.get_support()
print(u'有效特征为：%s' % ','.join(data.columns[rlr.get_support()]))
```

I got the error

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0;dimension is 9 but corresponding boolean dimension is 8
the rlr.get_support() index is 8 and data.colunms is 9
```

is this because my python is python 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not because of the Python version. It is because `data.columns[...]` expects an array of the same size, that is used as a mask (`True` values in the mask will include that element from `data.columns`, `False` values will skip it).

It is impossible to give more details with the amount of information you have provided.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code:

```
r1.get_support(indices=True)
print(u'有效特征为：%s' % ','.join(data.columns[rlr.get_support()]))
```

I think the reason for the Indexerror is the version of numpy.you can look at the docs。
[https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays][1]

Boolean arrays must be of the same shape as the initial dimensions of the array being indexed.